# Excluding current row value in window analytical Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, windowing

Using the window analytical function , I need to get max date - excluding the current row's column value

```
Account,Instrument,TrDate
1,A,3/1/2018
1,A,3/2/2018
1,B,3/3/2018
1,B,3/6/2018
1,B,3/6/2018
1,B,3/7/2018
2,A,2/7/2018
2,A,2/5/2018
2,B,2/15/2018
2,B,3/6/2018
```

### Expected Transformed DF

```
Account,Instrument,TrDate,MaxInDate,ExcInstrMaxDate
1,A,3/1/2018,3/2/2018,3/7/2018
1,A,3/2/2018,3/2/2018,3/7/2018
1,B,3/3/2018,3/7/2018,3/2/2018
1,B,3/6/2018,3/7/2018,3/2/2018
1,B,3/6/2018,3/7/2018,3/2/2018
1,B,3/7/2018,3/7/2018,3/2/2018
2,A,2/7/2018,2/7/2018,3/6/2018
2,A,2/5/2018,2/7/2018,3/6/2018
2,B,2/15/2018,3/6/2018,2/7/2018
2,B,3/6/2018,3/6/2018,2/7/2018
```

**ExcInstrMaxDate is calculated**

Get the Max TrDate within Account window excluding that specific instrucment
i.e for Accout 1, Instrument A, ExcInstrMaxDate is maxDate for Account 1 filtered by Instrument A

Comment: Tried two level windows ( account , account+ instrument).. But How to exclude the current instrument to get the excMaxDate

Comment: how did you create the dataframe?  update that code too and what is the logic behind excinstrmaxdate? and paste the text data not image

Comment: Account,Instrument,TrDate
1,A,3/1/2018
1,A,3/2/2018
1,B,3/3/2018
1,B,3/6/2018
1,B,3/6/2018
1,B,3/7/2018
2,A,2/7/2018
2,A,2/5/2018
2,B,2/15/2018
2,B,3/6/2018

Comment: what have you tried? are you doing in scala, python or R or something else?

Answer (score 0):

All you need are *two Window functions* one for the `MaxInDate` and other for `ExcInstrMaxDate`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("Account", "Instrument")
def windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("Account")
```

You would also need a `udf` function *to remove the current MaxInDate from the list of `MaxInDate` for *grouping* by `Account`*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def removeCurrentMax = udf((currentMax: String, listMax: Seq[String])=> listMax.filterNot(_ == currentMax))
```

And use both the `Window` functions and the `udf` function as

```
df.withColumn("MaxInDate", max("TrDate").over(windowSpec1))
  .withColumn("ExcInstrMaxDate", removeCurrentMax(col("MaxInDate"), collect_set("MaxInDate").over(windowSpec2)))
  .show(false)
```

You should be getting

```
+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------------+
|Account|Instrument|TrDate   |MaxInDate|ExcInstrMaxDate|
+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------------+
|1      |A         |3/1/2018 |3/2/2018 |[3/7/2018]     |
|1      |A         |3/2/2018 |3/2/2018 |[3/7/2018]     |
|1      |B         |3/3/2018 |3/7/2018 |[3/2/2018]     |
|1      |B         |3/6/2018 |3/7/2018 |[3/2/2018]     |
|1      |B         |3/6/2018 |3/7/2018 |[3/2/2018]     |
|1      |B         |3/7/2018 |3/7/2018 |[3/2/2018]     |
|2      |A         |2/7/2018 |2/7/2018 |[3/6/2018]     |
|2      |A         |2/5/2018 |2/7/2018 |[3/6/2018]     |
|2      |B         |2/15/2018|3/6/2018 |[2/7/2018]     |
|2      |B         |3/6/2018 |3/6/2018 |[2/7/2018]     |
+-------+----------+---------+---------+---------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Note that I have used `TrDate` as `StringType`**

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.  Actually we calculate ExcInstrMaxDate , we should not include any values related to current row value for Instrument ..to second argument do we need to send both date and instrument and filter ?

Comment: @SparkDev, I didn't understand your query. please clarify